# Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when its parent element (a table) changes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Handlebars to templatize a table. Inside the table, I have a modal. I'm using Sijax (Simple AJAX for Flask-Python) to continuously stream data. When new data comes in a JSON variable gets the new data and the template is redrawn with the new data. All of the elements on the table work. My problem is that when I click a modal and new data comes in, the table is redrawn and the modal disappears.

I want to prevent the modal from disappearing if it's possible, but I don't know the JS or HTML to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pull the modal out of the table in the DOM and position it relative to the table, or cell, or wherever it is supposed to be with css positioning.

You could also use jQuery's [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and save the modal element to a variable that you can re-insert into the table on re-render; hopefully passing it a handle so the table can update the modal as necessary.

You can also fire the event that causes the modal to open if the table re-renders and the modal was open before the re-render by saving a boolean you can check as needed.

Comment: #1 and #2 seem hacky. #3's what I was thinking of, but instead of re-rendering the table, I'd wait until the modal was closed to re-render it. How would I detect if a modal is currently open?

Comment: Well if there is an event that fires on open, you could do something like `window.modal_is_open = true;` and set it to `false` for the event that fires on close. If it is the case that you are re-rendering but window.modal_is_open is still true, you know you should be firing the modal-open event. You could set that event up as a "post-table-render" thing